# Where is "Default changelist" stored on disk in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

Where on disk (file system path) are file changes from `Default changelist` in PhpStorm stored before they are committed to cvs?

I backed up my projects in order to reinstall Ubuntu but I am pretty sure I will loose my uncommitted changes if they are stored in some other location than that of my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhpStorm does not "store" this anywhere.  CVS is tracking which files have changed and is notifying PhpStorm through a plug-in.  You need to make sure that you copy the CVS repository, wherever you have installed and configured the files to be stored.

Why not commit the changes to CVS first anyway?   If you must back up uncommitted changes, simply copy your project folder and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks, so I should be fine having copied projects' root directories. I could not commit changes to CVS because my system was unbootable, had to reinstall.